# SharePoint 2010 - Exchange 2010 -SMTP Outgoing email

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to setup the outgoing email settings on my sharepoint 2010 Server.

I have installed an exchange 2010 server out of the box but when I type in the FQDN address to the exchange 2010 server in the outgoing settings on the SharePoint 2010 page I'm not getting any emails from the sharepoint 2010 server.

How can I configure my Exchange 2010 server to work with SharePoint Server 2010 for outgoing email notifications?

I've tried looking at http://www.lazynetworkadmin.com/knowledgebase-mainmenu-6/2-windows/149-exchange-2010-configure-anonymous-relay-to-external-domains

Answer (score 1):

I was googling for similar info, found your question here, then found the following article:

http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-outgoing-email-sharepoint-2010/

It seems to have worked for me.

Tim